# Search for a text containing backslash in MySQL from GOLANG

Tags: mysql, go, sql-like

I have a mysql table with 3 entries (id ,title, content) (int, text, mediumtext)

A row of dummy data in the table looks like

| Id | Title | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple\"apple | apple\"apple, Hello world\t, dummytext |

My query intends to do a search on the fields title and content

The query that works to retrieve the data is shown below

```
select id from document where title like 'apple\\\\"apple' and content like 'apple\\\\"apple, Hello world\\\\t, dummy%' ;
```

I am trying to make this sql statement execute from a golang script. My script has a function which looks like the following

```
func retrievedoc(title string,content string, tx *sqlx.Tx) *sql.Row {

           title=prefix(title)

           content=prefix(content)

           existingRes := tx.QueryRow(`SELECT document.id from document title=? and content like ?`, title, content+"%" limit 1)

           return existingRes

}


func prefix(text string) string {

    prefix = strings.ReplaceAll(prefix, "%", "\\%")
    prefix = strings.ReplaceAll(prefix, "_", "\\_")
    prefix = strings.ReplaceAll(prefix, "\\", "%\\") 

    return prefix
}
```

The original values received by the function retrievedoc are

```
title=apple\"apple
content=apple\"apple, Hello world\t, dummytext
```

The prefix function aims at escaping % and _ as these are characters identified by the like clause. The problem with function is if title="abcd%efgh" then it gets replaced as "abcd%efgh". Now that "abcd%efgh" contains a \ again the backslash gets replaced and string turns into "abcd%%efgh"

How should I pass the title and content to the golang query? Should I manually convert the single backslash to 4 backslashes to make the query work or is there a descent way to achieve this?

Comment: When the query, using `where title like 'apple\\\\"apple'`, is working, the data contains `apple\\"apple`, and not `apple\"apple`

Comment: You might read about the [ESCAPE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) when doing your query

Comment: @Luuk When the query, using where title like 'apple\\\\"apple', is working, the data contains `apple\"apple

Comment: I am only talking from MySQL, not from sending the query from GO to MySQL.

Comment: I am not experienced in Go, But you can use [Raw String](https://www.golangprograms.com/golang-raw-string-literals-and-interpreted-string-literals.html) to stop messing around with replacing characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Raw String](https://www.golangprograms.com/golang-raw-string-literals-and-interpreted-string-literals.html) to stop messing around with replacing characters.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := `Go\tJava\nPython`
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

output:

```
Go\tJava\nPython
```